KMP Compose Multiplatform Datastore not working on JVM release build
I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform / Compose Multiplatform app with Android and Desktop as targets. I wanted to use DataStore to store some data locally, namely the user's refresh token and some other info.
I followed a tutorial from Philipp Lackner, and it worked perfectly. But when I installed the app from the release build, it stopped working on the desktop version. Through some testing I realized the problem occured when using the .edit() function of DataStore. It gets to the function, executes everything in it, but then never gets out of it. It's not that it just doesn't store my data or throws an error. It just never comes back from that method.
I really don't understand why it works on the debug build but not on the release one.
Has anyone used DataStore with KMP on Desktop ? And if so, did it work on the release build ?
The code I use :
The object I'm trying to save :
data class AuthInfo(
    val accessToken: String,
    val refreshToken: String,
    val userId: String,
    val email: String
) {
    companion object {
        fun getEmpty(): AuthInfo {
            return AuthInfo("", "", "", "")
        }
    }
}

The method to create my DataStore instance :
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.PreferenceDataStoreFactory
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import okio.Path.Companion.toPath

fun createDataStore(producePath: () -> String): DataStore<Preferences> {
    return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.createWithPath(
        produceFile = { producePath().toPath() }
    )
}

internal const val DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME = "prefs.preferences_pb"

My desktop Koin module :
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import org.koin.dsl.module

actual val platformDataModule = module {
    single<DataStore<Preferences>> { createDataStore { DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME } }
}

The class using it :
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.stringPreferencesKey
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.first
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

class EncryptedSessionStorage(
    private val preferences: DataStore<Preferences>
) {

    private val preferencesFlow = preferences.data

    override suspend fun get(): AuthInfo? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val json = preferencesFlow.first()[KEY_AUTH_INFO]
            json?.let {
                Json.decodeFromString<AuthInfoSerializable>(it).toAuthInfo()
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun set(info: AuthInfo?) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if(info == null) {
                preferences.edit {
                    it.minusAssign(KEY_AUTH_INFO)
                }
                return@withContext
            }

            val json = Json.encodeToString(info.toAuthInfoSerializable())
            preferences.edit {
                it[KEY_AUTH_INFO] = json
                // It executes code all the way to here
            }
            // Then never gets here
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val KEY_AUTH_INFO = stringPreferencesKey("KEY_AUTH_INFO")
    }
}


I have exactly the same problem with the Datastore call on JVM at the time of launching the application. The suspend method never returns. I don't see any error logs either. I am running the Deb file on Debian 12.8. Please someone respond. Thanks!

Seems solution from google issue tracker works:
nativeDistributions{
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            modules("jdk.unsupported")
            modules("jdk.unsupported.desktop")            
}

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280205600
